# Selenium Webdriver with Java (Angular application)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written below code for selecting mentioned values from the drop-down list.
Here I want to select only these `@data-option-array-index=1,3,5,9,28,34` from the drop-down list.
I want to use kind of array or loop in which it will run for these selected values only. **But I am unable to do it**.

```
element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='search-field']"));
element.click();
element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-option-array-index='1']"));
element.click();
String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='search-choice']")).getText();
System.out.println("Element text is: "+ text);
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Use findElements,

```
List<WebElement> choises=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='search-choice']"));
List<String> listValues= new Arraylist<String>();
for(WebElement choise : choises){
   listValues.add(choise.getText());
}
```